# trigger.io won't start after installation on Windows in spanish

Tags: trigger.io

this is a self answered question, it may be useful to others.

After installation, trigger.io won't start if the installation path includes special characters such as accented letters.

I found such problem after installing trigger.io on a windows XP in spanish machine (trigger.io installs in "C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data" which in spanish is "C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Configuración local\Datos de programa", there is an accented ó in the path).

The log file toolkit.log reported some kind of unicode error.

Here is a quickfix, assuming your filesystem is NTFS: 
 0. Uninstall trigger.io

1. create a [junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) for "C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Configuración local\Datos de programa" to a path without special characters, such as C:\USER\appdata.  You could use Mark Russinovich's [junction utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) to do that.
2. open regedit and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
3. Change the value for "Local AppData"  to the new path  and reinstall trigger.io.

By using a junction you don't have to copy the content from the previous dir to the new location, it's kind of a hardlink that works on directories.

IMPORTANT: this hack may have unintented consecuences on other applications, so use it at your own risk.